# How to set a scope value in angular's dropdown menu from the console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, dropdown

I would like to set/change a value in a dropdown menu that has been written in AngularJS in the Debugger located in the Developer Tools.

I have tried the following:

```js
angular.element(
    getElementsByClassName('input-group ng-pristine ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched')[0]
).scope().model = 'Incorrect PO'"
```

However it does not work. Usually when I debug Angular and I want to change a value of certain item - I put the 'ng-model' attribute at the end (in the example above the ng-model's attribute is called 'model').

```html
<select name="creditReason" 
    class="input-group ng-pristine ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched"
    id="creditReason"
    required="required"
    ng-change="change ? change() : _.noop()" 
    ng-model="model" 
    ng-options="type.value as type.name for type in list"
    ng-disabled="(disableField || disabled)" 
    ng-required="lookupRequired" 
    ng-attr-id="{{lookupId}}" 
    model="confirmDialogCtrl.creditReasonCodeId" 
    lookup="creditReasons" 
    lookup-required="true" 
    lookup-name="creditReason" 
    lookup-id="creditReason"
    ng-attr-name="{{lookupName}}">
  <option selected="selected" value="?"></option>
  <option value="number:39001" label="Customer Request">Customer Request</option>
  <option value="number:39002" label="Discount Not Applied">Discount Not Applied</option>
  <option value="number:39003" label="Duplicate Billing">Duplicate Billing</option>
  <option value="number:39004" label="Incorrect Address">Incorrect Address</option>
  <option value="number:39005" label="Incorrect Billing Method">Incorrect Billing Method</option>
  <option value="number:39006" label="Incorrect Cost Center">Incorrect Cost Center</option>
  <option value="number:39007" label="Incorrect Customer/Season">Incorrect Customer/Season</option>
  <option value="number:39008" label="Incorrect PO">Incorrect PO</option>
  <option value="number:39009" label="Incorrect Rate">Incorrect Rate</option>
  <option value="number:39010" label="Incorrect Rental Period">Incorrect Rental Period</option>
  <option value="number:39011" label="Sales Tax">Sales Tax</option>
  <option value="number:39012" label="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Could you please advise how to change the value of the dropdown menu?
I don't really understand the part with: `"ng-options" = "type.value as type.name for type in list"`

EDIT: Is anyone able to help me with this problem? :(

Thanks!

Comment: You should modify some array's element that represents your option. Take a look at [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). Are you using both ng-options and hardcoded `<option>`s or is this copied from DOM?

Comment: Hey,
I have checked your link before. Unfortunately it didn't really help me.
The above code have been copies straight from DOM.

I have debugged AngularJS plenty of times, however I am stuck on this one. I just want to enter Developer Tools, and write a code that will change the dropdown menu's value.

Thanks!

Comment: I missed the part about debugger... Have you tried setting model to `value`? like `"number:39008"` or `39008`?

Comment: Yes I did. Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: When you select some option, does `angular.element(/*your selector*/).scope.model` output anything?

Comment: When I type the following:
angular.element(/*my selector*/).scope.model in the debugger, I receive the following output:
"Customer Request" 

However - > The value in the dropdown menu is blank (nothing is set).

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the `$scope` using `.scope()`, you need to use `$apply` to set the `model` value. As per the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

> `$apply()` is used to execute an expression in AngularJS from outside of the AngularJS framework.

Using this, you can now update `model` from the console using the below code

```js
// Add the relevant classes to access the element.
// input-group should be sufficient if there are no other elements in the DOM with this class name.
const $scope = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("input-group")[0]).scope();
$scope.$apply(() => $scope.model = "number:39001")
```

or if you prefer to do this in a single line

```js
angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("input-group")[0]).scope().$apply(($scope) => $scope.model = "number:39001")
```

Comment: Hey nash11,
Thank you for your answer.
I have done everything as per your comments above and I receive: "Syntax error".

My code looks like this:
angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("input-group ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required")[0]).scope().$apply(() => $scope.model = "number:39001")

Comment: I have noticed that below in the Dom is the following line:
<!-- ngIf: confirmDialogCtrl.creditReasonCodeId === 39012 -->
Perhaps we need to make something like this?
What do you think?

Comment: My bad, I missed defining `$scope` in the single line answer, I have edited my answer. I tested this on a simple StackBlitz example I created (https://angularjs-pftesx.stackblitz.io/). Open the console and type `angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("input-group")[0]).scope().$apply(($scope) => $scope.model = "number:39001")` to change the model

Comment: Hi Nash,
I have done exactly the same, and still I receive "Syntax Error".
I have no idea what is wrong here.

Could it be possible that Internet Explorer does not support Arrow functions?

Comment: Hi again, I have tried under Google Chrome. This time the output in the console is:
"number:39001", however the value in the dropdown does not change.

Comment: Could you please advise if you have any more ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what more I can tell you without actually seeing what's going wrong. Because this works perfectly on my side. I shall tell the steps I followed exactly. I opened this link (https://angularjs-pftesx.stackblitz.io/). Opened the console, pasted this `angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("input-group")[0]).scope().$apply(($scope) => $scope.model = "number:39001")` and I see the dropdown change.

Comment: If it is Internet explorer and it doesn't support ES6 array syntax, then try this `angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("input-group")[0]).scope().$apply(function ($scope) { $scope.model = "number:39002"})`

Comment: Note: I have tested this on Firefox as well and it works perfectly fine. I don't have IE on my system, unfortunately. What is your Chrome version?

Comment: Hi nash11, I really appreciate all your help.
Unfortunately when I type the above code, I receive a message 'undefined'.

I have did the following test:
When I type "angular.element....scope()" before choosing an element, I see that when I open attribute confirmDialogCtrl, then one of its properties: 'creditReasonCode..." is null.
However when I change the value, then this attribute 'creditReasonCode...' equals for example : 39001.

Perhaps we should somehow change that attribute? I just don't know how.